Unexpected Output When Using /n in C++: Why Does It Print 12142?
I encountered a strange issue while working on a C++ program with Visual Studio 2021. When I used cout << '/n';, I expected it to simply print /n or values in ASCII(47110), but instead, it printed 12142. This behavior is confusing and I couldn't find a clear explanation for it.
I've tried to go Googling, but the only answers are very sketchy, so I'd appreciate a detailed answer, thanks! Hope someone can help me.

'/n' is a multi-character literal and, as such, has type int and an implementation-defined value.    If your intent is to print the pair of characters / and n,  then print a string literal (delimited by double-quotes, not single quotes)  i.e. do cout << "/n";

On the other hand if your intent is to print a newline you got the slash the wrong way round, use a backslash '\n'.

When you have a mysterious decimal number, converting it to hexadecimal quite often provides a clue. In this case, 12142 is 2F6E in hexadecimal; 2F is 47 and 6E is 110.

you are seeing multicharacter constant, look in character_constant and search for multicharacter constant.


multicharacter constant, e.g. 'AB', has type int and implementation-defined value.


you are just seeing the concatenation of the bytes of both / and n converted to an int, you can print them in hex to see their hex representation is equivalent.
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << '/n' << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hex << '/n' << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>('/') 
      << std::hex << static_cast<int>('n') << std::endl;
}

12142
2f6e
2f6e


Just use the double quotes:
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   cout<<"/n";

    return 0;
}

For anyone wondering why the value is 12142, the likely answer is that in the OP's implementation, '/' has the integral value 47, 'n' has the integral value 110, and these are "concatenated" into an int a la <47><110> (leaving endianness out of the picture), giving a value of 47*2^8 + 110 = 12142

Side note : in your examples do not use using namespace std; it is not a recommended practice

Also, in the example you spend 20 characters to save typing 5 characters. What a waste of effort!
